# How to single boot on surface pro 3 delete windows and format the ssd

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, surface

All instructions online show how to dual boot. I want to clean my ssd completely and single boot Ubuntu.

Booting from a usb stick is easy enough. I have done it several times. In fact the experience is a thousand times better under Ubuntu.

Can I just let the Ubuntu installer format the entire ssd and do it's thing ?

TIA

Comment: Yes. Although **I would suggest that you disable secure boot in the BIOS first**

Comment: secure boot disabled. I needed to disable bit defender and whatnot as well. I was thinking to just install ubuntu over the windows drive and not mess with reformatting. Im super nervous. Im never going to use windows on this thing. I was blown away just using the usb boot at how well ubuntu runs and functions.

Comment: You can easily reinstall Windows even if Ubuntu doesn't work properly. But yes, you need to format it with "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" because Ubuntu cannot be installed to NTFS

Comment: Also just keep in mind that you will probably have some issues with Ubuntu on there, and that's when you come back here for help :)

Comment: sorry i mis-typed bit locker and windows defender disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can just let the ubuntu installer erase everything and do it's thing, there will be an option to erase disk and install (might even be the default)

Comment: I just did it. thank you. I will update but for now it is running flawlessly

Comment: wow. this is unbelievable. far surpassing windows. I cannot believe these touch support!!!! It even gives me handles on the selection and the keyboard pops up automatic.

Comment: That's nice to hear, when you get the chance, try gnome, i hear that's quite nice on touch screens.

Comment: Smurf, already done my friend. kernel 4.10 has fixed the WiFi issues I had . before installing Linux headers I actually didn't have WiFi issues on 4.9 . I found an awesome screen rotation script and edited it a bit . works flawlessly. the only thing now is I want to get hold down to right click working. and am waiting for my keyboard cover to come this week. I will update my progress here and hopefully make a video.

Comment: I also would like to add to your answer that disabling Windows defender and bitlocker was very important. I also turned secure boot off but have a feeling if I went with the rUEFI (sp?) solution, I'd actually be able to hibernate the device without hiccups. I haven't tried hibernate or suspend since 4.10 kernel. I will do some testing and report back. for now, the volume buttons wake from screen lock just fine and even shaking the tablet works to come out of display sleep.

Comment: I cannot say how awesome onboard keyboard is. it even has type suggestions now which is way better then the windows keyboard was, plus resizeable. so awesome.